# Google Datastore authentication issue - C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-authentication

I'm trying to connect to the Google Datastore on my account with service account credentials file (which I've created according to the documentation), but I'm encountering with authentication error while trying to insert an entity:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated,
>   Detail="Exception occured in metadata credentials plugin.")

My code is:

```
var db = DatastoreDb.Create("myprojectid");
Entity entity = new Entity{
 Key = db.CreateKeyFactory("mykindname").CreateIncompleteKey()
};
var keys = await db.InsertAsync(new[] { entity });
```

The **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** variable refers to the credentials file and when calling GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync() to see if the credentials object is valid it indeed looks good...

I saw some earlier examples which used the GetApplicationDefaultAsync function togehether with some DatastoreService object - but I couldn't find the **DatastoreService** object (probably it was there in old versions...) in the latest .Net API: **Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1**

Notice that I **don't** want to use the other authenticaiton methods:

1) Using the gcloud cli.

2) Running from Google environment (app engine for example).

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I've replaced "license" with "credentials" in the question as the service account json file really contains credentials rather than a license. Just to check, where *are* you running the code?

Comment: Thanks. From my local environment...

Comment: It looks like this error is coming from [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.cs). Can you turn on gRPC logging to see the original exception? Is it the `InsertAsync` method that's failing, rather tha n`DatastoreDb.Create`? Do any other methods work?

Comment: (Let me know if you have difficulties turning on gRPC logging and I'll give you some details.)

Comment: Start searching on how to enable the logging :) if you can shed some light on this, it will be great :) It happens on the InsertAsync method, the DatastoreDb creation pass with no issues...

Comment: Also other method fails with the same authentication error... for example: LookupAsync

Comment: Okay - will write up a quick doc about turning on logging, in a public place. Give me 10 minutes or so :)

Comment: In fact, in your case you may be able to get away with just `GrpcEnvironment.SetLogger(new ConsoleLogger());` at the start of your code, with appropriate using directives as prompted by VS.

Comment: Cool! I've enabled it as you offered and saw that there was an issue loading one of the references (System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource). Fixed it and now everything works as expected. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'll write an answer - so if someone else will bump with this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the great help of Jon Skeet the issue was solved.

The authentication issues can occur if you don't reference all the required Datastore dlls. Make sure that all the dlls are referenced on the project that are running the calls to the Datastore.

I've added the Google Datastore lib via the NuGet to my test project and everything worked!

Notice that in such cases it is recommended to enable gRPC logging. `(For exmaple: GrpcEnvironment.SetLogger(new ConsoleLogger()), there you'll probably see if there were issues loading several dlls...

Comment: So how were you referencing the library before, if you hadn't added it via NuGet?

Comment: I've added it via NuGet to my library project, but not to my test project... The test project referenced the library project without referencing the Google Datastore dlls...

Comment: Hmm. I would have expected that to work, but it probably depends on the *exact* details (target framework etc). Transitive dependencies *should* just work, I'm sure... (They didn't work before nuget, but I'd hope that with nuget it would all be okay.)

Comment: For whom who might be interested, I've wrote a mini .Net ORM for the Google Datatore: https://github.com/NoGame/GoogleDatastoreORM

Answer (score 1):

Authentication can be broken if your system clock is significantly incorrect. Check your system time, and fix it if necessary, then try authenticating against Datastore again.

Comment: No, this wasn't the issue for the OP, as is seen by the accepted answer. While I can imagine some ways in which the system date/time could cause problems for authentication (in particular if it thinks the granted access token is immediately invalid) there's no indication that that was an issue in this case, and it's a less common cause than others.

Comment: I got the below error: Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occurred in metadata credentials plugin."). and i debug it. i think the token is generate based on the time zone, so my system date is modified based on my region. then my issue is solved.

Comment: No, the system time zone isn't used. The system *UTC* time is used, and that may have been wrong, but that's a different matter. And while I believe that your problem may have been fixed by changing time settings, that doesn't mean that was the solution for the OP, or that it's likely to be the case for others. I definitely don't mean to put you off contributing, and maybe it would be worth having your answer an an alternative that *could* help people that run into other auth problems, but currently the way you've written it makes it sound like you think it's always the case.

Comment: I didn't mean that.
I think this is one of the silly reason for authentication issues.
anyway, thank you, sir, for correcting me. :)

Comment: I've edited your answer significantly to reflect these comments - please check that you're happy with my rewording.

Comment: I am very much happy. thank you so much, sir. (Love You :) )