# Google NLP authentication/call issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlp, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am working on an MVC web application that uses [Google Natural Language Processing API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/) to parse different input from users.

I have successfully consumed and implemented the API operations and everything works fine as long as I run the application on my local machine. But as soon as I publish a version and upload it on a server I receive the following error on calling the API methods (e.g. AnalyzeSentiment):

```
Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occured in metadata credentials plugin.")
```

With the help of the answers from post: [Google Datastore authentication issue - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759933/google-datastore-authentication-issue-c-sharp) I was able to further get details on the error (using gRCP):

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
Stacktrace:    at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.<RequestAccessTokenAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Auth.GoogleAuthInterceptors.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<FromCredential>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.<GetMetadataAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
```

This seemed like an authentication issue so I double checked the jsonKey file which is fine. Please note, I have used code to set the credentials in Environment variables:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", jsonPath);
```

and verified it using:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
```

The call is made as follows:

```
private AnalyzeSentimentResponse AnalyzeSentiment(string statement)
{
    GrpcEnvironment.SetLogger(new MyLogger());

    var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create();
    var response = client.AnalyzeSentiment(new Document()
    {
        Content = statement,
        Type = Document.Types.Type.PlainText
    });

    return response;
}
```

Cannot figure out why it works fine when I run it on my local machine and fails when it is deployed on the server. There is also no restrictions of any kind on the said server.

The result for:

```
GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result.Underly‌​ingCredential.GetTyp‌​e()
```

is:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential
```

Note: The server is our own (Windows Server 2012R2)

Comment: Did you check whether the user that the MVC application is run as has permission to call [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx)? According to that page you will get a SecurityException if you are lacking permission to call it.

Comment: Note that linking to users in a question doesn't notify them. Hopefully we can sort this out though...

Comment: Could you log the result of `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result.UnderlyingCredential.GetType()` and report that in the question? Is the server you're deploying it on in Google Cloud Platform, or is it somewhere else (e.g. Azure or on your own computers)?

Comment: @NightOwl888: I don't think there is a permission issue, as you can see in the question, after setting the variable, I used the Get method to get it as well. Valid value was returned.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Updated the question with additional details as requested. Thanks

Comment: Okay, that looks like it should be fine. In particular, it's managed to load a service account correctly. The next potential issue is if your server is behind a firewall that isn't HTTP2 friendly. Are you able to run a simple console application on your server to try to diagnose this from a simpler environment than an ASP.NET app?

Comment: IMHO, the exception details should have been logged by this line: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/69d3e0984da394d1ea06edbe26de76d124c6eaf3/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.cs#L90 (besides the call being failed on the client side with the general message "Exception occured in metadata credentials plugin")  Can you please doublecheck your outputs?

Comment: Ok, the message actually got logged and it's the one posted "An error occurred while sending the request. Stacktrace:    at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler". Basically the google C# auth library is unable to obtain the auth token from google token server - which seems to be in agreement with the answer for this question (misconfigured machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion given by @JonSkeet, I copied the code into a console application and executed the call. Unfortunately, the issue persisted. What I did next was to move the console application onto another server, it worked there.

So, it was indeed an issue with the server where there maybe some features missing (the firewall is disabled). Network dept is checking it out whereas I have deployed my web application on another server.

**Update**: There was an issue on the server where some required framework features were not installed. The issue has been resolved by moving the deployment to another server.